# Parameters/methods in models in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've added an extra method to my model in rails, let's just say it is:

```
def subscribed
  true
end
```

If I create a form with:

```
<%= f.check_box :subscribed %>
```

it correctly prints a ticked checkbox, but on submission of the form it says

```
unknown attribute: subscribed
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you add the  subscribed attribute to your database with a migration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an attribute accessor like this:

```
class MyModel
  attr_accessor :subscribed
end
```

Comment: yeah it's the same but yours is cleaner, so there were no need to put another answer